# ReportViewer Control Parameter Security

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm considering using the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms ReportViewer control on an ASP.NET web form in a custom web app for displaying RDL reports.  The RDL reports use parameters.  One of the parameters is a department parameter.  Users in dept A should only be allowed to use A as the value for the parameter, users in dept B should only be allowed to use B as the value for the parameter, and so on.

The department parameter value (along with all other parameter values) will be set programmatically in the code behind logic for the ASP.NET web form hosting the ReportViewer control.  The server-side logic looks up the department parameter value based on the user's profile.  The report is configured so that the department parameter is not visible.

Here's my question: 
Are there any known back doors in the ReportViewer control whereby a user could pass a "department" value as part of an HTTP request and gain access to data for which they shouldn't have access?  Note that this question applies to both simple tabular reports as well as more complex drill through reports, where department may be a value passed from the main report down to the drill through report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends much on how you are using "security". If the users have access to the reports through Windows Authentication, and if they know where the reports reside (I guess that they can find out using F12 tools in the browser), they can of course use whatever parameters they want, when accessing the reports directly. Therefore, it would be best to implement the user-based restrictions in the source database (or, if possible, in the report) instead of in the report-consuming ASP.Net application.

Comment: Thanks.  Users will not have access to the reports directly.  All access will go through the application server.  The primary data source will be an Oracle database, so trying to embed user/role based restrictions within the data source will likely not be an acceptable solution (we would need to flow user identity from the app to SSRS/report to Oracle).  Our business goal is to make the the queries "easy" to write without imposing the burden of having to understand user/role security on the business users writing the queries.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. What I still don't know is: how does the application connect to the report server?

Comment: The app will use either Windows Auth or some other support SSRS auth type.  The SSRS server will be configured to only allow certain accounts to access the SSRS server.  The app will be using one of these "service" accounts to connect to SSRS.

Comment: All right, then it's quite safe (as safe as your web application). Just make sure to use HTTPS.